# JQuery chat is appending <scripts>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chat

I am building a simple chat app. The issue I have encounter is that users can insert scripts through the chat. Obviously this is not something I want.
A  (simplified version) of my code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 80px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            // on load of page
            $(function() {
                // when the client clicks SEND
                $('#datasend').click(function() {
                    console.log('enviar data');
                    var message = $('#data').val();
                    $('#conversation').append('<b>me:</b> ' + message + '<br>');
                    $('#data').val('');
                });
                // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
                $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
                    if (e.which == 13) {
                        $(this).blur();
                        $('#datasend').focus().click();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script src="scripts/locate.js"></script>
        <div class="container" ng-controller="userController">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="well">
                        <h3>
                            <span class="fa fa-comment"></span>
                            Chat</h3>
                        <div>
                            <div id="conversation"></div>
                            <input id="data" style="width:200px;"/>
                            <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For example, if an user inserts this text:

```
    <script> alert('big problem') </script>
```

An alert pops up. Any ideas of how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd try converting punctuation to their corresponding [HTML Escape Codes](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php).

Comment: You need either prevent HTML being typed in to the input, escape the HTML you append or both. If you add the HTML content using `text()` instead of `append()` to quickly escape the HTML

Comment: Never `.append()` or `.html()` any user-input strings or you are asking for XSS problems. Using `.text()` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to what CodingWithSpike commented I managed to get to this solution:

```
            // when the client clicks SEND
            $('#datasend').click(function() {
                console.log('enviar data');
                var message = $('#data').val();
                text = $('<span></span>').text(message);
                user = $('<b> </b>').text('me: ');
                div = $('<div> </div>');
                div = div.append(user);
                div = div.append(text);
                $('#conversation').append(message);
                $('#data').val('');
            });
```

After I got to this solution I looked at what Ciprian Turco posted. It also manage to do the trick but it removed some stuff. Thats why I prefer this solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need client side code and server side code to protect XSS
as for cleint code you can use this function

```
  function strip_tags (input, allowed) {


  allowed = (((allowed || '') + '').toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join('')

 var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi
 var commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi

 return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
   return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : ''
 })
}
```

usage :

```
var message = $('#data').val();
  message= strip_tags(message, '<br><br/><br />');
 $('#conversation').append('<b>me:</b> ' + message + '<br>');
```

also you can user php strip_tags function on server side

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

more infromation 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: What makes you assume he is using PHP?  I don't see anything PHP related in his tags or code

Comment: i gave the solution for client side as he want only for client side  didn't mention server side suggest solution for php any way if he have another language for server-side